# Cracking passwords following rules with John or hashcat

Tags: hash, windows, password-cracking, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I would like to crack the forgotten password of a very old archive file (rar) with JTR or hashcat.
I remember it was starting with a certain number from a set of numbers e.g.
prefix number from the set

- Npre= {12,13,25,50,..(a couple more)} -> specific numbers I can remember
  followed by a word from the set
- W1= {Black,White,Lazy,Eager, ...(a couple more)}
  followed by another word from the set
- W2= {Cat,Dog,Tiger,Elephant,Hippopotamus, ...(a couple more)}
  followed by a certain suffix number from the set
- Nsuff= {1915,1817,1685,2010,...(a couple more)}
  followed by a special character from the set
- C= {'!',':','@','#','%'}.

Additionally, the whole password (variant A) could have been starting with the character '!' or '@' or (variant B) maybe not!
Finally, I remember to have added (or maybe not) a special character such as '!' between each above listed numbers' and words' positions having NO two special characters repeated next to each other, and without putting the '!' character between the positions of the suffix number.
And I might have toggled the letters as well (or not).
Examples that follow the above defined rules:

1. @BlackHippopotamus1685!
2. @B!l!a!c!k!H!i!p!p!o!p!o!t!a!m!u!s!1685!
3. @BlAcKhIpPoPoTaMuS1685!
4. @B!l!A!c!K!h!I!p!P!o!P!o!T!a!M!u!S!1685!
5. @B!l!A!c!K!h!I!p!P!o!P!o!T!a!M!u!S!1685@
6. @B!l!A!c!K!h!I!p!P!o!P!o!T!a!M!u!S!1685!
7. !B!l!A!c!K!h!I!p!P!o!P!o!T!a!M!u!S!1685@
8. B!l!A!c!K!h!I!p!P!o!P!o!T!a!M!u!S!1685@
9. BlackHippopotamus1915@

I tried to implement this with dictionary attack using some rules, but I got stuck e.g.

- I created initially five set of dictionaries for the sets Npre W1, W2, Nsuff, C.
- Therein the toggles I did manually (this could be automated, but I couldn't figure out how exactly).
- I combined them in order (left/right) incrementally.
- In JTR config I added the rule i0@ i2! i4! i6! i8! iA! iC! iE! iG! iI! iK! iM! iO! iQ! iS! iU! iW! iY! to insert the '@' and '!'s. I could not find out what comes in INX after iZ! for example. (i11! is for example refused by JTR, so I had to go with the complete alphabet for representation of positions in hex.)

I couldn't achieve the passwords following the above explained rules as presented in above 9 examples.
Can someone please help?

Comment: This sort of problem isn't solved with the built-in features of these tools, but with a script to generate a dictionary.